# Read from excel file .xlsx using java Apache POI 3.9 Eclipse

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am trying to read a file from a `.xlsx` file using java. But I still get errors. I already corrected the `HSSF` to `XSSF` so it is able to read past 2007 version of excel. The code crashes when instantiating the workbook. Here is the code:

```
package excelread;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadExcel {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File excel =  new File ("C:/Users/Leah-Dina/Desktop/LogFile.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet("Input");

        int rowNum = ws.getLastRowNum() + 1;
        int colNum = ws.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        String [][] data = new String [rowNum] [colNum];

        for(int i = 0; i <rowNum; i++){
            XSSFRow row = ws.getRow(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++){
                    XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
                    String value = cell.toString();
                    data[i][j] = value;
                    System.out.println ("the value is " + value);
                }
        }

    }
}
```

Here you can see the error message I get:
Seems like everything is imported and I have no idea whats wrong.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:154)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.<init>(OPCPackage.java:141)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.<init>(Package.java:54)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:82)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:267)
        at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:204)
        at excelread.ReadExcel.main(ReadExcel.java:21)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, make sure that all libraries that Apache POI depends on are on your classpath.  In this case, you are certainly missing Dom4J (dom4j-1.6.1.jar).  Possibly you may be missing other libraries, such as stax-api-1.0.1.jar, xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar, and poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar.  All necessary libraries are included in the distribution that is downloadable from the [Apache POI website](http://poi.apache.org/download.html).

Line 21 appears to be this line:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

So there may be a problem with your spreadsheet.  Putting Dom4J on your classpath will only allow the `DocumentException` to be created, but hopefully that will tell you what's really wrong with your spreadsheet (if anything).

Comment: Thank you, I really was missing some libraries. I did not realize that they are in different folders. It helped so far. Thanx))

Answer (score 2):

> You should include dom4j-1.6.1.jar file

Answer (score 0):

simply paste your poi libs in your web-inf lib directory if you are working in eclipse IDE.