# Apache POI Read xlsx NPE

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am trying to read an Excel Spreadsheet using the exact code in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282378/read-from-excel-file-xlsx-using-java-apache-poi-3-9-eclipse?answertab=active#tab-top). Everything works fine but sometimes I get an NPE on some cells on this line of code:

```
String value = cell.toString();
```

Why is that? How can some cell be null in the middle of my worksheet? Admittedly, the cells on which I get the NPE don't contain data. But not all the empty cells cause NPEs.

Likewise (if I wrap this line in an NPE check) I will eventually get some rows that are apparently null:

```
XSSFRow row = ws.getRow(i);
```

Again, these are rows in the middle of my spreadsheet that contain no data. But not all empty rows cause NPEs.

Obviously performing a check for null in both of these cases solves my immediate problem. I'm just wondering why object are null sometimes. There must be some logic to it. I just don't see it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't have to be a `Row` object for all rows.  Think about it, when you start a new spreadsheet in Excel, you can have up to 1,048,576 rows, yet saving an empty spreadsheet results in a file size that is small.  That is, references to rows that don't exist would result in an absolutely *huge* file.  References to rows should only be stored if there is some kind of content associated with them -- any of cell values, formatting, borders, etc.  A row may appear blank but have some formatting or maybe it used to have content that is now gone. There is a similar argument for `Cell`s in a row.  There's no reason to have a `Cell` reference for cells that aren't even used.  But you can remove the content of a `Cell` and not have the `Cell` itself be removed; it can be a `CELL_TYPE_BLANK` cell.

If it never existed, then it will be `null`.  Even if it has no content, it may have formatting that needs to be represented, so it won't be `null`.  If it used to have content or formatting, then it won't be `null` unless someone explicitly deletes it, either in Excel with Right Click -> Delete or in POI with `removeCell` or `removeRow`.

If the row doesn't have any content, then it makes sense that it could be `null`.  As you have mentioned, you can always check the `Row` returned by `getRow` if it's `null` before accessing it, and you can always check the `Cell` returned by `getCell` if it's `null` before accessing it.  You can also supply a `Row.MissingCellPolicy` to [`getCell`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell%28int,%20org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.MissingCellPolicy%29) to control that method's behavior.  `CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK` will create the `Cell` for you if it didn't already exist.  Imagine having 16,384 `Cell`s for a `Row`, where usually only a few at most are needed.

(There are other missing cell policies.  `RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL` does the opposite; if it exists but is blank, then `null` will be returned.  The default, `RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK`, just returns whatever is there without any other action.)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. As I don't have control over the spreadsheet I'm receiving, I'll do a null check after retrieving the row or cell.